# HTML / JS popup box

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to have a popup box show, **not `alert`**.

You know the ones that popup in the centre of the screen, not as a separate window, but just as a content wrapper, also blurring the background and making items in the background unclickable?

I can't find much, but if anyone has any ideas or a link to another post, please say!

Thank you!

Comment: something like this ?https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/MMVbJv

Comment: "I can't find much"... Use search terms like "dialog", "modal"... heck, even "javascript popup" brought back ~27,900,000 Results in a search engine...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I would have.. If I knew what they meant. I'm learning

Comment: My comment was a suggestion for how to search further, since this question is off-topic.

Comment: Ok, thank you. @HereticMonkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until [`dialogInstance.showModal()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal) is available in all browsers, you can use something like [CSS Only Modal](https://codepen.io/brob/pen/jLqmqw)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this kind of stuff, you can consider two best frameworks which provides the best solution for modal popup, slider, search, etc

1. Bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/
2. Semantic UI https://semantic-ui.com/ (I love this option)

Hope It'll help